# How to access session data in a signal handler?

Tags: django, django-authentication, django-signals, django-1.7, django-sessions

Whenever a visitor who is not a user adds content to my site I just create a dummy user account and store it's id in the session of that visitor.

Now when a visitor finally logs in using Facebook, Google or any other OAuth I want to merge the dummy user with the real user account. I figure a good way would be to catch the login signal. But in order to find the previous dummy user account I need to enter the session data. How can I get to it from within the handler?

If it's not possible than how to approach this problem?

Please note that I want to be able to use various login apps like django-social-auth so I need a solution that hooks in very clean.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

The login signal includes the current `request` as one of it's parameters:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/ref/contrib/auth/#module-django.contrib.auth.signals

Something like:

```
@receiver(signal=user_logged_in)
def merge_accounts(sender, request, user, **kwargs):
    user.update_details_from(request.session['your-dummy-data'])
```